# How to find the selected Flipview control index on selection changed

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm developing an application in that,Flipview control it is having two flipview itemtemplates on selection changed(flipview) i need to get the selected index of the flipview is that possible.Which i have tried like this

```
private void _fvDashboard_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index=_fvDashboard.SelectedIndex;
        if (index != -1)
        {
            if (_fvDashboard.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                btnScrBoard.Background = new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper.FromArgb(255, 54, 54, 54));
                btnItem2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));

                btnItem1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper.FromArgb(255, 210, 222, 235));
                btnItem1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));

                _fvDashboard.SelectedIndex = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                btnItem1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper.FromArgb(255, 54, 54, 54));
                btnItem1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));

                btnItem2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper.FromArgb(255, 210, 222, 235));
                btnItem2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));

                _fvDashboard.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT i just need the index number when the flipview control changed but not getting the controls name or something inside the flipview itemcontainer.Is it possible or not that the thing i need.

Comment: The SelectedIndex property will give you the index of the currently selected. If you keep reference to it, SelectedIndex will also give you the index of the previously selected. I hope that's what you want.